# Detect the end of request on ApiController

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, controller, httpwebrequest, asp.net-web-api, detection

I am developing a web application with MVC4 and found pretty useful this method:

```
class Controller
{
    protected virtual void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext);
}
```

Which allows me to call `UnitOfWork.SubmitChanges();` or `Transaction.Rollback();` or other good stuff which needs to be called only after the request is processed and the changes to database are pending.

When I started to work with `ApiController` I did not found that useful method.

How can I detect the end of http requests on my web-api controllers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a [`ActionFilterAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.actionfilterattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) for the ApiController.

```
 public class JsonpAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            //Logic
        }
    }
```

And in your controller:

```
[Jsonp]
public class testcontroller : ApiController
```

Note that Web Api uses `System.Web.Http.Filters` whereas MVC4 uses `System.Web.Mvc`